# Which constructor is called first

Tags: c++, exception, constructor

Following code is from "exception handling" in . The author tried to tell us that by making everything an object, we can prevent resource leaks. 
My question:
Why the constructors of 'cat' and 'dog' are called earlier than constructor of 'useresources'?

```
//: C07:Wrapped.cpp
// Safe, atomic pointers
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;
ofstream out("wrapped.out");
// Simplified. Yours may have other arguments.
template<class T, int sz = 1> class PWrap {
    T* ptr;
public:
    class RangeError {}; // Exception class
    PWrap() {
        ptr = new T[sz];
        out << "PWrap constructor" << endl;
    }
    ~PWrap() {
        delete []ptr;
        out << "PWrap destructor" << endl;
    }
    T& operator[](int i) throw(RangeError) {
        if(i >= 0 && i < sz) return ptr[i];
        throw RangeError();
    }
};
class Cat {
public:
    Cat() { out << "Cat()" << endl; }
    ~Cat() { out << "~Cat()" << endl; }
    void g() {}
};
class Dog {
public:
    void* operator new[](size_t sz) {
        out << "allocating an Dog" << endl;
        throw int(47);
    }
    void operator delete[](void* p) {
        out << "deallocating an Dog" << endl;
        ::delete p;
    }
};
class UseResources {
    PWrap<Cat, 3> Bonk;
    PWrap<Dog> Og;
public:
    UseResources() : Bonk(), Og() {
        out << "UseResources()" << endl;
    }
    ~UseResources() {
        out << "~UseResources()" << endl;
    }
    void f() { Bonk[1].g(); }
};
int main() {
    try {
        UseResources ur;
    } catch(int) {
        out << "inside handler" << endl;
    } catch(...) {
    out << "inside catch(...)" << endl;
    }
} ///:~
```

Comment: They aren't. But they are called before `out << "UseResources()" << endl;`. When you enter the body of your constructor, all member objects will have had their constructors called.

Answer (score 3):

> Why the constructors of 'cat' and 'dog' are called earlier than constructor of 'useresources'?

They are called earlier than the **body** of the constructor of `UseResources` is entered.

`UseResources` has two data members which are instantiations of the `PWrap<>` class template. The constructor of `PWrap<T>` instantiates a number of objects of type `T`:

```
ptr = new T[sz];
```

Thus resulting in a corresponding number of call to the constructor of `T` (`Cat` or `Dog`, in your case).

Since your `PWrap` objects are data members of `UseResources`, their constructor gets executed before the body of the `UseResources` constructor is entered. This is how object construction works in C++.

The rationale behind this is to make sure that when the body of a constructor is entered, the constructor of all the subobjects (including both base subobjects and *member* subobjects - such as `Bonk` and `Og`) has been completed.

This way, a constructor can rely on using valid subobjects whose class invariant has already been established by the time it gets executed.

This is how Paragraph 12.6.2/10 of the C++11 Standard describes the process:

> In a non-delegating constructor, initialization proceeds in the following order:
>
> — First, and only for the constructor of the most derived class (1.8), virtual base classes are initialized in
>   the order they appear on a depth-first left-to-right traversal of the directed acyclic graph of base classes,
>   where “left-to-right” is the order of appearance of the base classes in the derived class base-specifier-list.
>
> — Then, direct base classes are initialized in declaration order as they appear in the base-specifier-list
>   (regardless of the order of the mem-initializers).
>
> — **Then, non-static data members are initialized in the order they were declared in the class definition
>   (again regardless of the order of the mem-initializers)**.
>
> — **Finally, the compound-statement of the constructor body is executed**.
>
> [ *Note*: The declaration order is mandated to ensure that base and member subobjects are destroyed in
>   the reverse order of initialization. —*end note* ]

Answer (score 1):

The order of constructor calling is:

1. Base class.
2. Members, in order they appear in the header
3. Class constructor.

The class UseResources is "constructed" before the body of the constructor is called, with regards to it having a size, and the member variables having proper addresses. However they are not yet fully constructed.

The body of the constructor can assume that all its members are already fully constructed (with their constructors called), thus they have to be called in this order.

Thus Bonk and Og have their constructors called in that order before UseResources.

Answer (score 0):

In the code segment:

```
   UseResources() : Bonk(), Og() {
      out << "UseResources()" << endl;
   }
```

Actually you are calling UseResources constructor before constructing Bonk and Og members but just outstreaming your log later